# Streaming data/file to a REST service. Files/attachments with huge size

Tags: rest, email-attachments

I am trying to figure if there is a way to stream large files chunks by chunks using HTTP transfer-encoding CHUNKED between client and server in REST. By Semantics REST service provider accepts only application/json, but I read this [Chunked Transfer Encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding) and thinking if this is something I can make it possible using any REST client, say for example apache Http client.
Handling large files (memory overhead will be more during normal/huge loads) is always a challenge with REST API during transfer, so is there an optimistic solution for this.

If not chunking is there any other way like reading bytes into fixed buffer and transmit over HTTP. The service provider is not willing to change the REST contract and always expects `application/json` media type with attachment being a part of multipart request.

The usecase that comes to my mind is how to handle attachments in email typically big in size.

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

The main use-case for Chunked transfer encoding is sending data for which you can't accurately predict the Content-Length.

So if your JSON is built up dynamically, and you can't accurately know in advance how many bytes it will be, chunked is the way to go.

However, if you *can* predict the `Content-Length`, it's not needed to use Chunked, and you shouldn't, as there is a bit of overhead in doing so. Chunked is not a requirement for streaming responses.

Also note:

- Most programming languages/HTTP frameworks will automatically use Chunked encoding in circumstances where the Content-Length cannot be predicted. For Node.js this is for example any time you just write to the response stream, and for PHP this is basically always unless you explicitly set a `Content-Length`. So in many cases there's basically nothing you need to do to switch to this.

- Chunked no longer exists in HTTP/2 as HTTP/2 has its own framing protocol that supports responses with unknown sizes.

Comment: i am streaming json by bytes from upstream, rather reading all into memory I wanna keep them writing to the REST service provider as and when I read(/buffer) those bytes. So i still doubt if chunked doesn't fit here? If not what else can rescue here, rather polluting/occupying overall jvm memory just for these json's if I had to read them fully. Sizes may vary from 1MB to 30MB. This might seem to be less size but at load of 200TPS, this matter significantly. Please suggest

Comment: @user2585494 understood. My point is that this is unrelated to chunked encoding.

Comment: Thanks! Does node.js/php supports this use case by any means? I am not good in those technologies, but if i have them as a solution (optional), then I can consider building a client using them. What do you say

Comment: Any HTTP/1.1 or HTTP/2 client supports this. 99% of server technology does too.